# Require string input for moment to be of certain format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

It doesn't seem like moment's date parsing functionality is working as I would expect it.  The [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) says the following:

> If you know the format of an input string, you can use that to parse a moment.
>
> `moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");`

I have the following code:

```
moment(value, "MM/DD/YYYY");
```

As I'm testing, I'm entering strings that do not adhere to the `MM/DD/YYYY` and yet they are parsed successfully as valid moment date.

For example, `1-1-asdf` resolves to `01/01/2018`.

How can I specify one or more date formats that should be used for string parsing and if it does not match a specified format, the parsed moment will be invalid?

Comment: Moment is trying to be clever. If you want to explicitly reject invalid formats, use a regex pass first. That said, what’s wrong with accepting more kinds of date format?

Comment: @MTCoster Because I don't want moment's cleverness to result in `1-1-asdf` being parsed as a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick validation, you could use a regex check:

```js
if (!/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/.test(value)) {
  // Invalid date string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment has a "strict" mode for parsing dates:

```
moment("1-1-asdf", "MM/DD/YYYY").toString() => valid, parsed as 01/01/2018
moment("1-1-asdf", "MM/DD/YYYY", true).toString() => invalid, parsed as "Invalid date"
```

Refer to https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ for more info.